# Problems with the code \include{chapter}

Tags: thesis

I am preparing my PhD thesis in latex. In the format that I have, I see, more than once, the code \include{chapter#}, where # is the appropriate number. I am guessing it is supposed to "bring over" a chapter from somewhere, but I am completely clueless how that works. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Make a new text file in  the same working directory with the name `chapter1.tex` and type here  `\chapter[Introduction]{Nice Introduction} Foo and more foo. End dot.`  Then save the changes. Now open the main file and comment all these include commands  (just put  a `%` before) except  in `\include{chapter1}`. Now compile the main file and it should work (at this respect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\include{chapter4}`  just includes a file `chapter4.tex` there is nothing special about numbers, if chapter 4 is about dogs you could call the file `dogs.tex` rather than `chapter4.tex` and use `\include{dogs}`